# Как реализовать список в html

Tags: html, html5

При нажатии на картинку открывался список . Хотелось бы как здесь  https://onloog.com/ . Скажу честно в этом деле новичек .

Comment: Такс и что у вас не получилось сделать? На каком этапе возникли проблемы?

Comment: На спам похоже, учитывая направленность ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать за счёт "табов (Вкладок)".

```js
$('.tabs-block .tab-link').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    var parentTabs = $(this).closest('.tabs-block');
    parentTabs.find('.tab-link.active, .tab-content.active').removeClass('active');
    var elemIndex = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    parentTabs.find('.tab-content').eq(elemIndex).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.tabs-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-link-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4184f3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tab-link {
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #bbb;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-link:not(.active):hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.tab-link.active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  color: #fff;
}

.tab-content-block {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  min-height: calc(50px - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fefefe;
  color: #333;
}

.tab-content:not(.active) {
  display: none;
}

.tabs-block .tab-link-block {
  height: 50px;
}

.tabs-block .tab-link-block::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.tabs-block .tab-link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  min-width: calc(50px - 20px);
  max-width: calc(150px - 20px);
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.tabs-block .tab-link.active {
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #f4b142 inset;
}

.tabs-block .tab-link:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.tab-link {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  transition: all linear .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs-block">
  <div class="tab-link-block">
    <div class="tab-link active">Первая вкладка</div>
    <div class="tab-link">Вторая вкладка</div>
    <div class="tab-link">Третья вкладка</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content-block">
    <div class="tab-content active">1</div>
    <div class="tab-content">2</div>
    <div class="tab-content">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник](http://pandora.clan.su/publ/1-1-0-58)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала при помощи CSS нужно спрятать все списки которые должны появиться (display: none), создаете новый класс со свойством "display:" и необходимым значением. Например:

```
.list-show { 
    display: block;
}
```

Далее при помощи JS ловите событие нажатия на картинку и пишите условие, в котором при нажатии на картинку к вашим спискам добавлялся класс .list-show.